# How can I write statistical analysis output to separate text files in R?

Tags: r, loops, output, analysis

Can someone please help me with the following?

I have to conduct many statistical analyses with the same predictors but different outcomes. So far I managed to write a script that does the analysis. But I would like to write the output of the analysis to separate text files with the outcome name as the file's name.

Here is some test data:

```
subject age sex country race service cancer
1   19  2   2   0   1   0
2   34  2   4   0   0   1
3   36  1   4   0   0   1
4   36  2   7   0   0   1
5   18  1   7   1   0   0
6   34  2   3   0   0   0
7   37  2   3   0   0   1
8   46  1   3   1   0   0
```

Here is my script so far:

```
lapply(c("race", "cancer"),

   function(var) {

       formula    <- as.formula(paste(var, "~ age + sex + country"))
       res <- lm(formula, data = test)

       summary(res)
   })
```

What I would like next is that for the variable  "race" a separate output text file with the summary(res) will be created and named "race". And also a separate text file called "cancer" with the summary(res) of that analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
lapply(c("race", "cancer"),

       function(var) {

         formula    <- as.formula(paste(var, "~ age + sex + country"))
         res <- lm(formula, data = test)
         summary(res)
         capture.output(summary(res), file = paste(eval(var), ".txt", sep = ""))

       })
```